# Cellular automata on a Hex grid

Tags: java, oop, grid, hex

I'm learning java so I try to code a basic cellular automata on a hexgrid.

I want to separate display code from simulation code so the simulation just process calculations and the display refresh itself based on it.

I try to figure out for days how to properly do this but I'm still confused. I've found many resources on the internet but none gives a simple walkthrough to code this in a object oriented way.

For now I don't care about implementing any pattern, a simple continuous movement on the x and y axes would be good enough to check if it works.

So what I've done :

- a GUI with go, pause, clear controls and a blank display Jpanel

If somebody could give me a method or skeleton or any advice on how to achieve this it'd be really appreciated.

Comment: ever thought about using Netlogo?

Comment: Get the program to work without any GUI at all first - just display the output to the terminal.  Once you have that working its not very hard to develop a simple GUI around that

Comment: @Bradley: Are you familiar with and are you using MVC techniques?  The first thing to do is to create your model in a GUI-agnostic way.  Once this is well constructed, construct the GUI and control class that use the model.  edit: as Amir said just before I did. :)

Comment: @ITroubs yeh but I need to learn java, so re-using existing classes is not the best way imo

Comment: @Amir & @Hovercraft You're right I'll try to have a simple model running first. Should the output be an array ?

Comment: Netlogo is not reusing of existing classes. Netlogo is a Simmulation Framework used to do big common simmulations

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
class MyModel {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }

    public void go() {
        // sart a thread that changes x & y over time
    }
    public void stop() {
        // stop the thread
    }
    public void reset() {
        // reset x & y to their initial values
    }
}
```

The above is your model. Your view should monitor changes in the model's x and y values and display movement based on that. Your controller should call the model's "go" method when the user taps the "go" button, etc.